# Install github clones of a python package to WinPython

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to install a package, pybrain, from its github website. It does not have nicely packaged archive files or executables, so I don't know how to install it via WPPM.

Do I still do python setup.py install, or do I copy the pybrain folder manually to the site-packages? I figured one thing I can do is to

```
python setup.py sdist
```

to generate an archive file, and then use WPPM to do it. Is this the "best" way?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Sorry that I don't have enough reputation to initiate the tag of "WinPython".

Answer (score 1):

Most packages that are configured properly with distutils will automatically place themselves in the correct location with "python setup.py install"

Answer (score 1):

Having had similar issues, especially sitting behind a corporate firewall, I found the easiest way to install things from github repositories is to download the repository as a zip file, then use the WPPM to add the package from there. Github repositories give the option of downloading as a zip on the right hand side. I've found that the package manager handles everything correctly from there.